# Populating a combo box with the first word of a textfile

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, file-io

So I feel like im pretty close, but I also have a feeling I am mixing up StreamReader and ReadAllLines

....................................................................................

Option Strict On

Imports System.IO

Public Class Form4

```
Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter

Private Sub Form4_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("c:\devices.bat", False)
    file.WriteLine("@echo off")
    file.WriteLine("cd " & Form1.TextBox2.Text)
    file.WriteLine("adb devices > C:\devices.txt")
    file.Close()
    Shell("C:\devices.bat", AppWinStyle.Hide, True, 500)

    Dim output() = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\deviceinfo2.txt")
    Dim Devices As String = ""
    Dim line() As String = {}

    For X = 1 To output.Count = -1
        line = output(X).Split(New Char() {("     ")})
        Devices = line(0)
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(Devices)

    Next

    output.Close()
    output.Dispose()

End Sub
```

End Class

........................................................................

What I am trying to have it do is to start reading on line two of devices.txt and then read the first word from each line until the text file is done.

It seems simple enough, but like I said, I think I am mixing streamreader with readalllines

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Class Test
    Public Sub Main()
        Try
            ' Create an instance of StreamReader to read from a file.
            ' The using statement also closes the StreamReader.
            Using sr As New StreamReader("TestFile.txt")
                Dim line, firstWord As String
                Dim i as Integer = 0
                ' Read and display lines from the file until the end of
                ' the file is reached.
                Do
                    line = sr.ReadLine()
                    If Not (line Is Nothing) AndAlso i > 0 Then
                         firstWord = line.Split(" ")(i)
                        'do your logic
                    End If
                    i += 1
                Loop Until line Is Nothing
            End Using
        Catch e As Exception
            ' Let the user know what went wrong.
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Grabbed this from MSDN and modified it. It should compile, but I didn't test it. This will loop through the lines, 1 by 1, skip the first line and grab each line's first word after. Hope this helps.

Comment: I operated under the assumption that "first word" would mean it was followed by a space and that it's first character was the first character on the line. If that's not the case, the split will have to be changed or you'll have to parse the string for whatever starts a "first word" and however it ends.

Comment: it starts on the second line, but it takes the second word from the second line and cant find the 3rd and 4th lines

Comment: I figured it out: firstWord = line.Split(CChar(" "))(0) FTW

Comment: Sorry about that i mishap. Testing fail. =) Glad you got it, man.